# How to fix 'Failed to build gem native extension.' for several ruby packages?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, byebug, ruby-debug-ide

I can't install ruby-debug-ide and byebug.

The command:

`sudo gem install byebug`

Gives me this error:
[image]

The command:

`sudo gem install ruby-debug-ide`

Gives me this error:

[image]
[image]

And they both give me the same error:

"Failed to build gem native extension."

Are both problems part of the same problem or are they different problems?

---

Update:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Solved my problem installing byebug

The ruby-debug-ide is still giving me this new error:

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext. Images of plaintext are not appropriate on stackoverflow. Copy and paste plaintext into your post.

Comment: Why are they not appropriate?

Comment: [Lots of reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gem install rake
```

and then

```
sudo gem install ruby-debug-ide
```

Did the job for ruby-debug-ide.

And for byebug:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and then:

`sudo gem install byebug`